# Carrierwave different size limits for different file types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have a list of allowed file extensions

```
def extension_white_list
  %w(pdf doc docx xls xlsx html tif gif jpg jpeg png bmp rtf txt)
end
```

and a size limit validation defined in the model

```
mount_uploader :inv_file, InvFileUploader

validates_size_of :inv_file, maximum: 25.megabyte, message: "Attachment size exceeds the allowable limit (25 MB)."
```

It works fine and the size limit validation is applied on all defined file extensions.

But i want to apply different size limits for different files i.e

- 5MB limit for (png & jpeg)
- 20MB limit for PDF
- 25MB limit for all other file extensions

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this way

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base 
  mount_uploader  :inv_file, InvFileUploader

  validate :file_size

  def file_size
   extn = file.file.extension.downcase
   size = file.file.size.to_f
   if ["png", "jpg", "jpeg"].include?(extn) && size > 5.megabytes.to_f
     errors.add(:file, "You cannot upload an image file greater than 5MB")
   elsif (extn == "pdf") && size > 20.megabytes.to_f
     errors.add(:file, "You cannot upload an pdf file greater than 20MB")
   else
     errors.add(:file, "You cannot upload a file greater than 25MB")       
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: You are not checking, in the else, that file is over `25MB`. You are always throwing an `You cannot upload a file greater than 25MB` error in the case extensions doesn't match `["png", "jpg", "jpeg"]` or `"pdf"`.